# Did "Hexe" originate from Greek "ἑξα, hexa"?

Tags: etymology

Usually German words containing the letter "X" are loanwords from Greek words containing the letter **Χῖ**.

In other European languages a *"Hexe"* is named very differently: witch (English), sorcière (French), bruja (Spanish), strega (Italian), ведьма (Russian), thus indicating that there may not be a common language root.

This makes me wonder if *"Hexe"* originated from the Greek word ἑξα for the number 6 (that would make sense in the light of [666](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_the_Beast) being a symbol for the devil).

Is there anything known on the etymology of *"Hexe"*? Have there been or are there other synonyms that may share a common etymologic root with other languages? Where does the letter "**X**" come from?

Comment: Hexagons are a good way to ward off witches... the hex is gone. Proceed to laughter.

Comment: »X« (in a word, not as single letter) is pronounced exactly like »ks«. So when you find a word in German vocabulary that contains an x, then it is very likely, that there is an older variation of this word with *ks* or *gs* instead of the *x*. Also »chs« (like in the German word for the number 6: »sechs«) is pronounced the same way (that's why »sechs« and »Sex« have an identical pronunciation in German: [zɛks]). So, when you see an »x« in a German word, also try to replace it with »chs« when you are looking for an etymological root.

Comment: Hilft das hier vielleicht? https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexe#Etymologie

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sometimes self-explanations sound better than the bare facts!

Kluge (24. Auflage) says:

> **Hexe** Substantiv Femininum, Standardwortschatz (10. Jh.), mittelhochdeutsch *hecse*, althochdeutsch *hazissa*, *hagzussa* u.ä., 
>   mittelniederländisch *hagetisse*. Aus westgermanisch *haga-tusjO*
>   (o.ä.) fem. "*Hexe*", auch in altenglisch *hägtesse*. Der erste
>   Bestandteil ist *Hag*, das an das Gehöft angrenzende, aber nicht mehr
>   voll zu ihm gehörende Gebiet. Außerdem scheint es - nach altnordisch
>   *túnrida*, mittelhochdeutsch (14. Jh.) *zunrite* "*Zaunreiterin, Hexe*" zu schließen -, dass in der germanischen Vorstellung von Hexen,
>   diese auf dem Zaun (oder Dachfirst) reiten. Der zweite Bestandteil
>   könnte zu voreinzelsprachl. *dhwes-* "*Geist*" gehören, vgl. litauisch
>   *dvasià* "*Geist*" und dehnstufig mittelhochdeutsch *getwAs* "*Gespenst*". Näher am Germanischen ist ein seit Augustinus den Kelten
>   zugeschriebenes übernatürliches Wesen *Dusius*, das auch in dem
>   westfälischen Wort *Dus* für den Teufel gespiegelt sein kann. Offenbar
>   handelte es sich um ein Wesen, das bis zum Hag des Gehöfts mächtig
>   war. Das germanische Femininum ist entweder ein weibliches Gegenstück
>   oder eine Frau in der Macht eines solchen Wesens, im Mittelalter ganz
>   in vom Christentum geprägte Vorstellungen gekleidet. (...)
>  Ebenso
>   neuniederländisch *heks*, neuenglisch *hag*.

And about *Hag*:

> **Hag** Substantiv Maskulinum, erweiterter Standardwortschatz, obsolet (8. Jh.), mittelhochdeutsch *hac* maskulinum und neutrum,
>   althochdeutsch *hag*, *hac* Stammwort. Sonst mit n-Flexion
>   altsächsisch *hago*, *hag* maskulinum(?), altenglisch *haga*,
>   altnordisch *hagi* aus germanisch *haga-/On* maskulinum "*Umzäunung
>   (umzäuntes Grundstück, Weideplatz, Hecke)*". Außergermanisch
>   vergleicht sich lateinisch *caul(l)ae* femininum "*Schafhürden*" (aus
>   *caholae*), kymrisch *cae* "*Gehege*". Weitere Herkunft unklar. Die Sippe macht nicht den Eindruck einer altererbten Wortfamilie.
>   Ebenso neuniederländisch *haag*, neuenglisch *haw*, neuschwedisch
>   *hage*. Siehe zunächst *Hagebuche* und (stärker lexikalisiert) *Hagestolz*, dann mit anderer Lautform *Hain* und *hanebüchen*, mit Geminate *Hecke* (und *Heck*), semantisch abweichend *hegen* mit
>   *Gehege* und vielleicht *Hexe*, auf Umwegen verwandt ist *Kai*.

It would be very interesting to know the etymology of the other terms you named.

Comment: So you should specify your question - you asked for the etymology of *Hexe*. But as you can see: Not every **x** originates from a greek word. I agree that it is an interesting question why there's sometimes an **x** and sometimes, as from the word-origin, a **ks**.

Comment: Soweit ich mich erinnere, wird in mittelhochdeutscher Literatur hin und wieder auch ein **x** anstelle von **ks** verwendet, mitunter auch dort, wo heute ein **ks** zu finden ist. (Es gab damals ja noch keine großräumig vereinheitlichte Schreibweise. Ein Beweis ist natürlich noch zu erbringen.)

Comment: Sehr überzeugend klingt mir das, was Kluge da von Hag sagt, nicht. Eine Logik sehe ich da nicht. Über den zweiten Bestandteil scheint Unsicherheit zu bestehen. Könnte sogar sein, dass Hexe ursprünglich ein postiver Begriff war, so was wie weise/heilige Frau, altgriechisch hagia/agia),zB pflanzenkundig, medizinische Kenntnisse, und erst später ins Negative verdreht wurde.

Comment: *Zaun* soll mit En. *town* zusammenhängen (und m.M.n. auch *Zahn*), also wäre die *Dorfrätin* denkbar, oder wozu sonst *-reiterin* gehören soll. Die Wurzel soll Keltisch sein. Für was Slavisches, vgl. *BabaYaga* ... yechse? Schickse?

Comment: Die im Zuge der Christianisierung eingeführte *Verteufelung* heidnischen Brauchtums erschwert die Nachvollziehbarkeit daher erheblich. Kluges Beitrag ist daher nur als etymologisch relevanter Aberglaube zu werten-- um nicht falsche Folksetymologie zu sagen.

Answer (score -1):

Quoting the etymological dictionary regarding 'hectic'--this may also be a derivation for 'hex': Greek hektikos ‘habitual,’ from hexis ‘habit, state of mind or body.’

A hex is something that would affect a person's state of body or mind.

Comment: Which dictionary are you quoting here? And is the link from the Greek _hex_ to the German _Hexe_ made by this (or an other) etymological  dictionary or by yourself?